# ps -x|grep works on command line but not in shell script, why?

Tags: bash, grep

I am trying to find whether a particular process ID is running. If I type on command line:

`ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep 7032`

I get 7032 as the answer. But if I put into shell script:

`read pid_found < "ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep $old_pid"`

I get the error message:

`./test.sh: line 11: ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep 7032: No such file or directory`

Note that the expansion of $old_pid is a not a problem -- the error message correctly says `grep 7032`. Every similar question on StackOverflow has answers suggesting to use

`variable_name=$(command)`

but this does not work for me either, with *any* command. At least

`read variable_name < "command"`

works elsewhere in the script

Edit: I managed to get it to work by removing all pipes within quotation marks and putting all intermediate values into files. It's ugly, but it works:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/automan/vms_feed

read -d $'\x04' old_pid < "OldPID"

ps -x|cut -c1-5 > "Processes"

grep $old_pid "Processes"|wc -c > "PID_found"
read -d $'\x04' pid_found < "PID_found"

echo "Running: test, old_pid =" $old_pid
if [ $pid_found -gt 0 ]
then
   echo "Running: test, old pid found" $pid_found
else
   echo "Running: test, old pid not found"
fi
echo $$ > OldPID
echo "Finished: test"
```

Comment: try: `read pid_found < <(ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep $old_pid)` or `pid_found=$(ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep $old_pid)`

Comment: Now I am getting ```syntax error near unexpected token `<'```

Comment: assuming no issues with cut-n-paste into your env, shouldn't be getting a syntax error; are you running under `bash`? what does `bash --version` return?

Comment: bash --version returns ```GNU bash, version 4.1.2(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)```

Comment: that version of `awk` is fine; `read pid_found < <(ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep $old_pid)` runs without problem in my `bash 4.4.12` env; I don't see how `read variable_name < "command"` *works elsewhere in the script* ... ??? what's the shebang in the first line of your script?

Comment: I added the entire script as it stands now, at the end of the question

Comment: Yes, OldPID is the name of a file. It contains just one 4 or 5-digit number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238572/discussion-between-ilya187-and-markp-fuso).

Comment: Oops. ```source /etc/profile2``` is a carryover from what the script was before; it is unnecessary. But without it, I get exact same errors.

Comment: are you saying `source /etc/profile2` was the first line of your file? if the answer is 'yes' then I'm guessing you're not running `bash` at your command prompt, so your script runs under the same shell as your command prompt and generates the error; at the command prompt run `type bash`, assuming this displays `/usr/bin/bash` then edit your script and add `#!/usr/bin/bash` as the first line in your script, save the edit, get out of the editor and run your script (`./<script_name>`) and see if you still get the error message

Comment: On my system it is ```/bin/bash```, not ```/usr/bin/bash```, but yes adding ```#!/bin/bash``` as the first line and running ```./test.sh``` resulted in exact same errors. To be sure, I reverted the line ```read pid_found < <(ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep $old_pid)``` back to ```read pid_found < "ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep $old_pid"```, and again it gave me ```./test.sh: line 7: ps -x|cut -c1-5|grep 32032: No such file or directory```

Comment: 32032 is what was in the file OldPID at the time

Comment: `read pid_found < "ps -x ..."` is trying to read the contents of a file named `ps -x ...` hence the error message that `ps -x ...` is an invalid file (`No such file or directory`); still not sure what the issue (`syntax error near unexpected token <` ??) with `read pid_found < <(ps -x ...)` as I use this all the time without issue

Comment: I see. Next thing to try is send the output of ```ps -x|cut -c1-5``` to an actual file, then do a grep on it.

Comment: I do not get it, why don't you just do `variable=$(command)`.  I just tried `var=$(ps -x |cut -c1-5|grep "12579"` and $var contains 12579.  Why use `read` to assign values to a variable?  Anyway, look at this for assigning values with read when you use pipes: https://www.unix.com/unix-for-beginners-questions-and-answers/283674-using-read-assign-value-bash-variable-not-working.html

Comment: Odd. Not sure what I was doing wrong initially, but now that I tried what Nic3500 suggested, it works fine